# Using ion-img waiting for url key?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am wanting to use ion-slides with ion-img to produce a gallery since I am thinking there may be a fair no of images. ion-img in ionic 4 uses lazy-loading to fetch the images which I think is what I want.

I am fetching the images from an Azure storage account which needs to have a dynamic (expiring) key added to it when the url is fetched.

I have managed to make this work pretty well as follows, heres the html:

```
  <ion-slides #photoslider [options]="sliderOptions"
  (ionSlideDidChange)="checkKeyandFixText()"
  (ionSlidesDidLoad)="checkKeyandFixText()">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let i of userService.user.Images">
        <ion-img cache="true" width="50%" [src]="i.ImageUrl + validKey"></ion-img>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

which checks the key (and fixes up an index for text use with each load or image change).
The check key function is this:

```
  checkKeyandFixText() {
    console.log(this.validKey);
    this.userService.getStorageURLKey('').then(() => { // trigger key update
      console.log(this.validKey);
    });
    .... more irrelevant stuff
  }
```

the 'validKey' used in the html is updated by the 'getStorageURLKey function, because that function fires the service that gets the key and updates an observable, which is set up in the ngOnInit - part of which includes:

```
   this.azureKey$ = this.userService.azurekey$.subscribe((res) => {
      this.validKey = res.Key;
   });
```

But this is unreliable, depending on the state of the key and all manner of async timing possibilities.

Its been a bit of a road to here, stating with the idea that writing the 'getStorageURLKey' function would work, by providing the url, it checking if the current key is valid or not then if not getting one, and adding it back.
That function by necessity returns a Promise which the ion-img seems unable to cope with. (Here is the function for completeness:

```
        async getStorageURLKey(url: string): Promise<string> {
        const nowplus5 =  addMinutes(Date.now(), 5); // 5 mins to give some leeway
        console.log(nowplus5);
        console.log(url);
        console.log(this.azurekey);
        if (!this.azurekey || isBefore( this.azurekey.Expires, nowplus5 )) {
          console.log('Getting new Key');
          const keyObj = await this.getAzureKeyServer().toPromise();
          await this.saveAzureKeyStore(keyObj);
          this.azurekey = keyObj;
          console.log(this.azurekey);
          return url + keyObj.Key; // Return the url with the new Key or just the key if url is blank
        } else {
          console.log('Key is valid till ' + this.azurekey.Expires);
          console.log(this.azurekey.Key);
          const rval = Promise.resolve(url + this.azurekey.Key);
          return rval ; // Key is in time so return it with url
        }
      }
```

If I just call the function from inside the html:

```
    <ion-img cache="true" width="50%" [src]="userService.getStorageURLKey(i.ImageURL) "></ion-img>
```

it just loops forever due to angulars retry and event loops. If I pipe the result to async:

```
    <ion-img cache="true" width="50%" [src]="userService.getStorageURLKey(i.ImageURL) | async "></ion-img>
```

Then it loops over the images the requisite no of times but doesn't do anything else... sometimes, then sometimes it seems to just make no difference and loops forever.

I have also tried adding my own custom pipe instead of the async but the inbound value always comes in as 'undefined'.
Changing the html just to reference "i.ImageURl | urkKey", here's the pipe I tried:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'urlKey'
})
export class URLKeyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  userService: UserService;

  transform(value: string): any {
    console.log('At Pipe');
    console.log(value);
    this.userService.getStorageURLKey(value).then((key) => {
      console.log(key);
      return key;
    });
  }
}
```

I have tried a lot of things...:-s

Fundamentally I need to add an an async key to an async url and seem to be looped up in angular. Am I approching this wrongly, or should I just go try using plain old img instead?
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: getStorageURLKey returns a promise, async pipe works with observables.

Comment: try it like this ```getKeyForImage(url: string) {
return from(this.getStorageURLKey(url))
}```

Comment: <ion-img [src]="getKeyForImage(url) | async"></ion-img>

Comment: I'm afraid that just causes the infinite loop problem again. tbh. I cant see how that is much different from putting it directly in the html and piping to async? But thank you for trying...

Comment: Hmm... Ive managaged to make it reliable. Using the (somewhat rather over complex) method I stated at the top, but of course the fact that I was cacheing the image (cache="true") in the html meant that the url was cahed with an expired key.
Removing that makes it check the key every time, sadly though it means a lot more wasted bandwidth if the key expiry is short. So I think I'll set the the key to expire after a couple of hours or so. Its set to 30 seconds at the moment for teting purposes.